# Key not valid for use in specified state after IISRESET

Tags: encryption, session-cookies, wif

I have created a **Custom STS Login Application** and logging in/out functionalities were working fine. But if i login as some user and do **IISRESET** and then reloaded the page the below error is spitted. (But as expected it works fine after I cleared the cookies and logged in again :) )

Apppool user for STS Application is "A" and he has never windows logged into the server machine, where STS Application is deployed(he is in administrators group and has access to encryption certificates).

I tried to login once as "A" in to the server(**Windows Login**) and after that all of a sudden this issue is solved.

**Can anyone tell why was it not working after IISRESET and working after windows logging in once?**

Server Error in '/’ Application.

**Key not valid for use in specified state**.

[CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state.]

```
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded)
[InvalidOperationException: 1D1073: A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to decrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see inner exception for details).
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +433
Microsoft.IdentityModel .Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte] cookie, Boolean outbound) +189
Microsoft. IdentityModel .Tokens. SessionSecurityTokenHandler. ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +894
Microsoft. IdentityModel .Tokens. SessionSecurityTokenHandler. ReadToken(Byte]] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +118
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenrrocCookie(Byte] sessionCookie) +363
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web. SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFroaCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +124
Microsoft. IdentityModel .Web. SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +61
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionstep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
System. Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.D.30319; ASP NET Version:4.O.30319.272
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running with the default WIF config, the keys used to secure the session tokens are handled through DPAPI and are stored in the user profile. These keys change on iisreset unless you configure IIS with "Load User Profile" as true.

If you're running on .NET 4.5 the easiest approach would be to configure machineKeys for your application and use the new `MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler`, as documented in [Wif and Web Farms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545457%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem as i found out. We fixed it by using Certificate based session cookie encryption and decryption because we faced problems with Load balanced servers.

Comment: static var _CookieTransforms = new ReadOnlyCollection<CookieTransform>(
                new CookieTransform[] { 
                    new DeflateCookieTransform(), 
                    new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(certificate), 
                    new RsaSignatureCookieTransform(certificate) 
                });

public CustomSessionSecurityTokenHandler()
            : base(_CookieTransforms)
        {

        }

Comment: That will also work - it was the common solution for WIF 3.5. If you're running on load balanced servers I assume you've already specified a machinekey for the application. The new machinekey based token handler would've saved you the hassle of installing the certificate. :) Glad you got it working.